How to populate the post_tag in WordPress with a value from an ACF field in a frontend form?
i'm using ACF-form() to display a form in front end and populate the CPT ACF field with the value entrered by the user. So far it's working great, i have a problem though with the post_tag of wordpress, i want to use one of the field value to populate it. So far i have this code but it's not working.
# Save the actual time when user click submit
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'set_submit_time' );
function set_submit_time($post_id) {
    update_field('field_663785df67806', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), $post_id);
}

add_action('wp_head', 'add_acf_form_head');
function add_acf_form_head() {
    acf_form_head();
}

add_shortcode( 'frontend_form', 'display_frontend_form' );

function display_frontend_form() {
    ob_start();
    
    $post_tag_value = get_field('field_6637a50a428cd');
    
    acf_form(array(
        'post_id'       => 'new_post',
        'post_title'    => true,
        'form'          => true,
        'new_post'      => array(
            'post_type'     => 'test-review',
            'post_status'   => 'pending',
            'post_tag'      => $post_tag_value,
        ),
        'field_groups'  => array(6929),
        'submit_value'  => 'Submit Review',
        'updated_message' => __("Thank you, your review have been uploaded and pending.", 'acf'),
        'return'        => '?updated=true', // Prevents the form from being output directly
    ));
    ?>
    <script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const paramName = urlParams.get('name_des');

        if (paramName) {
            const field = document.querySelector('[name="acf[field_66379788628dc]"]');
            const field01 = document.querySelector('[name="acf[field_6637a50a428cd]"]');

            if (field) {
                field.value = paramName;
            }
            if (field01) {
                field01.value = paramName;
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}

/*change the post title label in the group field with the key = group_66377e81b91e2*/
/*https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/front-end-form-title-label/*/

function my_acf_prepare_field( $field ) {
    // Check if the field group key matches
    $group_field = acf_add_local_field_group(array('key' => 'group_66377e81b91e2'));
    if($group_field) {
        $field['label'] = "Give your review a title";
        $field['instructions'] = "";
    }
   return $field;
}
add_filter('acf/prepare_field/name=_post_title', 'my_acf_prepare_field');


$post_tag_value = get_field('field_6637a50a428cd');


'post_tag'     => $post_tag_value,

The tag is still empty, Those two line doesn't work i guess. Any idea? please..
update:
i have tried 'tax_input' => array( 'post_tag' => array ($post_tag_value) ),
based on that ACF frontend form wordpress category not working.
But same not working.
UPDATE:
I found one solution, i can use the acf/save_post and it worked like a charme. Thanks
See solution below
`function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {
    // Get the value of the ACF field
    $post_tag_value = get_field('field_6637a50a428cd', $post_id);

    // Check if the value is not empty
    if( !empty($post_tag_value) ) {
        // Add the term to the post
        wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, $post_tag_value, true );
    }
}

// Run after ACF saves the $_POST['acf'] data
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 20);`

